# jQuery animation mouseenter-mouseleave on bricks

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'd try to animate bricks without CSS3 features.
I have several blocks side by side. When mouseenter brick, information inside this brick as to switch (brick-off > brick-on) and on mouseleave, go back to original (brick-on > brick-off).

You can find example here : [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JdNz5/) (Frameworks used : jQuery + jQuery UI)

```
$('.brick').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    // hide previous brick-on displayed
    $('.brick-on:visible').hide("drop",{ direction: "down" }, 200, function(){
        $(this).prev('.brick-off').show("drop",{ direction: "up" }, 100);           
    });

    $(this).children('.brick-off').hide("drop",{ direction: "up" }, 200, function(){
        $(this).next('.brick-on').show("drop",{ direction: "up" }, 100);
    });
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).children('.brick-on').hide("drop",{ direction: "down" }, 200, function(){
        $(this).prev('.brick-off').show("drop",{ direction: "up" }, 100);           
    });
});
```

But I have problems with mouseenter/mouseleave actions. Sometimes when you rollover fast on bricks, some brick keep their mouseenter state, and they don't have to normally because I'm out.

Can someone explain how it can work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the animation part does not recognize the `mouseleave` event when you add an animation type for `hide()` or `show()`. In your case you used `drop`.

when you only aply the speed for the `hide()` or `show()` functionality, the `mouseleave` event does get recognized.

```
$('.brick').each(function() {

$(this).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".brick-off").hide( "fast" );
    $(this).children(".brick-on").show( "fast" );
});

 $(this).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".brick-on").hide( "fast" );
    $(this).children(".brick-off").show( "fast" );
});

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdNz5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children('.brick-off').hide("drop",{ direction: "down" }, 20, function(){
    $(this).next('.brick-on').show("drop",{ direction: "down" }, 10);
});
```

**The problem is mouseenter().**

I have tried to change your timespeed into 20ms and 10ms. It means mouse must be in the .brick class in 30ms and when the mouseleave() it should be work.

Solution:
Change the timespeed or the better way is delete drop from your line. Because it is bug, I could not find how to solve this issue. The code should be like this:

```
$(this).children('.brick-off').hide( 200, function(){
    $(this).next('.brick-on').show( 3000);
});
```

I put 3000ms (3 seconds), and it is still come back to normal when mouseleave().